# Importing a class from parent python file

Tags: python, python-packaging

My structure looks like this:

```
main_dir
- code_1.py
- sub_dir
    - code_2.py
-__init__.py
```

Now in code_1.py I define a class (a custom OpenAi Gym Env for that matter) that I want to use in my code_2.py. When using PyCharm everything works just fine, I can import the class like this

```
from main_dir.code_1 import GymEnvClass
```

I do not want PyCharm to be a requirement to execute the scripts (in this example `code_2.py`), so it should just run from the terminal.

I tried setting a `__init__.py` in the `main_dir` or relative imports like `from ..code_2 import GymEnvClass` but when I try to run it from terminal it always fails `ModuleNotFound: No Module Named main_dir` or `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder

Comment: I found a solution with appending the parent-dir to sys.path and importing inside of __init__.py . PyCharm now shows a red line indicating an error. It works but I do not really like the way this is handled. I still wonder how PyCharm is able to find the correct files ..